# is a wcf service with secured endpoint and non secured dualHttpBinding endpoint possible?

Tags: web-services, wcf, security

I'm busy trying to figure out how to enable security on one of my endpoints in my WCF service.

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to have 1 wcf service in which there are multiple endpoints which have different security configurations.

Endresult should be a service with the following endpoints:

- wsHttpBinding (non secured)
- wsHttpBinding (secured)
- wsDualHttpBinding (non secured)

I'm wondering if this is possible because:

- One of them now has been "secured" and therefore I needed my baseAddress to move to https.
- The WCF book I have says that https/ssl is not possible for a wsDualHttpBinding

Do I need to start hosting my wsDualHttpBinding on a different service?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple endpoints to one service, while each endpoint is responsible for its configuration, including security.

Setting the host:

```
ServiceHost host=new ServiceHost(typeof(CalcService));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (ICalc), new NetNamedPipeBinding("internalBinding"),
            "net.pipe://127.0.0.1:5000/CalcService");
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalc), new BasicHttpBinding("secureBinding"), 
            "http://127.0.0.1:5001/CalcService");
```

Here configuration is obtained from App.config, which can look like this

```
 <bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBinding" openTimeout="00:01:00"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            transferMode="Streamed">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647"
              maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
              maxArrayLength="2147483647"
              maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
              maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="internalBinding" openTimeout="00:01:00"  closeTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:30:00" receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, my question revolves around the fact that I have to set the baseaddress to either http or https and I have a combination of an endpoint with a wsDualHttpbinding which does not seems to support https and an endpoint with security which seems to requires https. When I configure it for https I get the following error when running the host: "Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding WSDualHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https]."